# how do you merge parititons if another partition is between the partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, kubuntu, merge

i already have 2 operating systems and i want to install another one but it needs 8,5GB of space, and i have that but one of my operating systems is in between the two partitions i want to merge,m can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven’t provided much information but in principle you can do the the following:

1. Back up anything you cannot afford to lose
2. Delete the first partition you wanted to merge.
3. Move the sandwiched partition into the space created in step 2.
4. Expand the other partition to take up the space created by step 3.

None of these partitions can be in use while doing this . Hopefully you can do this from one of your operating systems or alternatively boot a live environment. GParted is a good tool to use for this and there are plenty of guides on YouTube if you haven’t done anything like it before

Comment: thank you for your help because now i understand it better